# Should an Entity Framework join contain the table within the parent table?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got the following entity defined:

```
public partial class ImportConnection
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int fkCompanyID { get; set; }
    public int fkUserTypeID { get; set; }
    public int fkDataConnection { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime RecordCreated { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RecordUpdated { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionName { get; set; }
    public bool isEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool isPrimary { get; set; }
    public bool ManageUsersOnImport { get; set; }
    public bool ManageGroupsOnImport { get; set; }
    public bool isValidated { get; set; }
    public bool isErrored { get; set; }
    public int XLoc { get; set; }
    public int YLoc { get; set; }
    public int FrequencyInMinutes { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ScheduledStartTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualStart { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> QueuedTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActualCompletion { get; set; }
    public int LastRunLengthTime { get; set; }
    public string ImportQuery { get; set; }
    public string IdentityColumn { get; set; }
    public string LastRunMessage { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }  //<---- here
    public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; } 
    public virtual DataConnector DataConnector { get; set; } //<---- and here
}
```

I'm loading the table from the DB using the following query. I'm also joining the two other tables. If I run this in SQL Server Management Studio (having to modify the query a bit) I get the company and dataconnector so I know the data is ok in the DB (the keys match).

```
List<ImportConnection> dcList = await (from data in db.ImportConnection
                                       join dc in db.DataConnector on data.fkDataConnection equals dc.id
                                       join co in db.Company on data.fkCompanyID equals co.Id
                                       where data.ScheduledStartTime < DateTime.Now
                                          && data.isEnabled == true
                                          && dc.isValidated == true
                                          && !data.isErrored
                                       select data).ToListAsync();
```

However, after it loads the query I get the data from `ImportConnection` but `Company` and `DataConnector` are both null.

Shouldn't the tables from the join show up in the top entity object? If so, what could be causing the issue with data not showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will resort to convention defaults for FKs if you don't configure it with the naming convention your schema uses. When you've set up navigation properties you do not need to add Joins in your Linq expression, just `.Include()` them to eager-load them, or let EF Lazy Load them on demand.

If you have migrations enabled you may find that your table has columns like "CompanyID" added following EF's default convention.

To configure your FKs:

```
[ForeignKey("Company")]
public int fkCompanyID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserType")]
public int fkUserTypeID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("DataConnection")]
public int fkDataConnection { get; set; }
```

Then to query:

```
List<ImportConnection> dcList = await db.ImportConnection
    .Include(x => x.DataConnector)
    .Include(x => x.UserType)
    .Include(x => x.Company)
    .Where( x => x.ScheduledStartTime < DateTime.Now
        && x.isEnabled
        && x.DataConnector.isValidated
        && !x.isErrored)
    .ToListAsync();
```

The other thing to check is that your relationships are set up properly for a many-to-one, not one to one. In EF6, if a relationship is marked as one-to-one then EF will use the PK on both tables as the relating FK.

I.e. if your EntityTypeConfiguration / modelBuilder config references:

```
.HasRequired(x => x.Company)
    .WithRequired(x => x.ImportConnection)
```

Where the ImportConnection has a Company and the Company has an ImportConnection, then EF will be joining this CompanyId on Company with ImportConnectionId on ImportConnection. This can lead to issues where expected or incorrect data comes back from relationships.

It should be a many-to-one connection:

```
.HasRequired(x => x.Company)
    .WithMany() // Assuming Company does not have a collection of ImportConnections.
    // or .WithMany(x => x.ImportConnections) if it does.
```

This is one reason I explicitly configure EF rather than rely on convention. This way either EF tells me there is a problem, or behaves the way I can inspect and correct rather than guess and what convention it's interpreting.

Comment: This query worked, what is the difference between my linq query and yours? I assume it's the .include.  Is the lambda the only want to get the .include portion of the query?

Comment: Include eager loads the related entities, which does the inner join and populates the entities. Using "join" will also join the related tables, but that's more suited to using Projection with `Select`, as I don't believe that will eager load any related entities. By default EF6 will have lazy loading enabled so accessing the navigation property would load the related entity. However if lazy loading is disabled (some teams disable it to avoid performance traps) then the navigation properties would remain #null.

Comment: Lazy loading is disabled so that is probably why I was seeing that. Thanks for explaining this, Steve.